# cmake suppress finding package and set path manually

Tags: cmake, include-path

I'm currently automating my the installation process for multiple instances of an application. This application uses `cmake` for building and uses some libraries for which no `findModule.cmake` files exist. Since I'm could find a good example how to generate a findModule.cmake file for existing libraries for example OpenCascade. When setting up the buildprocess manually one can easily adapt the include and lib path in `ccmake`. Since I want to automate this I'm looking for a way to do this by passing the options to `cmake` on the command line. Here is how I try to achieve this for OpenCascade:

```
cmake -DOCC_FOUND:INTERNAL=TRUE -DOCC_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/opencascade -DOCC_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/libTKernel.so -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release ..
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Since the option for building are build-depended, passing a previously configured `CMakeCache.txt` file is not working.
Thanks for any suggestions to achieve what I'm trying to do.